# A table contains name and amount field. Amount can be positive or negative. Query to delete names for whom total amount is 0

Tags: database

A table contains name and amount field. Amount can be positive or negative. Amount is positive if debited and negative if credited. Query to delete names for whom total amount is 0.

Comment: Is that some kind of exam question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried nested query "delete from table_name where name in(Select name,sum(amount) as total from table_name group by name having total =0);" . But I am getting error in this.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name , sum(amount) as total FROM table_name group by name having total =0;
```

same way Delete query would be:

```
Delete FROM table_name group by name having sum(amount) =0;
```

Comment: @Deep this query is not working in mysql. I am getting error.